# How does this java code involving recursion and arrays work?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how this code works. I understand basic recursion, like the factorial code, but I cannot seem to follow through this code. If someone could explain to me how to follow through this code, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
public class Question3 {

    public static int mystery(int[] a){ 
        return mystery(a,0);
    }

    public static int mystery(int [] a, int x) {
        if (x == a.length-1)
            return a[x];
        else {
            int z = mystery(a, x+1);
            System.out.println(z);
            if (a[x] > z)
                return a[x];
            else
                return z;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int[] testArr = {4, 23, 5, 11, 7};
        System.out.println(mystery(testArr));
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe try to use the debugger to step through the code line by line and step into the recursion. This might give you a better understanding. But in words: this code first goes to the end of the array provided, compares the values by going step by step to the left, returns the current max value, and by doing this ends up with the max value of the array and prints it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should notice that the array `a` is neither replaced nor modified in the entire code. This means that `a.length-1` will always evaluate to `4`.

The code has the following call stack:

```
main()
  mystery(testArr)
    mystery(testArr, 0)
      if block: 0 != 4
      mystery(testArr, 1)
        if block: 1 != 4
        mystery(testArr, 2)
          if block: 2 != 4
          mystery(testArr, 3)
            if block: 3 != 4
            mystery(testArr, 4)
              if block: 4 == 4 // returns testArr[4]: 7
            z = 7 // prints "7"
            a[3]: 11 > 7 // returns testArr[3]: 11
          z = 11 // prints "11"
          a[2]: 5 <= 11 // returns z: 11
        z = 11 // prints "11"
        a[1]: 23 > 11 // returns testArr[1]: 23
      z = 23  // prints "23"
      a[0]: 5 <= 23 // returns 23
    returns 23
  prints "23"
```

So the `mystery` goes to the end of your array and then returns from back to front the current maximum element observed so far and prints it. In the end you will get the maximum element of the whole array.

Comment: I understand up to where 7 is printed, then I get a bit confused. Why does the value of x suddenly go down, and how do we have a value of Z that isn't 7?

Comment: `x` is al local parameter in the scope of the method. The `7` is printed in the call `mystery(testArr, 3)`, so `x=3` in the whole method. That `mystery(testArr, 4)` does not affect the value `x` in the local scope of `mystery(testArr, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

This method is recursively checking what is the highest number, `System.out.println(mystery(testArr));` will print `23`, the highest number. If you update the array with another numbers will be able to check that.

Out of clarity, you could change the `mystery(int [] a, int x)` method to:

```
public static int mystery(int [] a, int x) {
    if (x == a.length-1)
        return a[x];
    else {
        int z = mystery(a, x+1);
        System.out.println(z);
        return Math.max(a[x], z);
    }
}
```

Emphasis in `return Math.max(a[x], z);`. And would be clearer what is trying to do. Picking up the higher number and recursively checking it against the next one.